# Exporting github action run step output in GITHUB_ENV

Tags: github-actions

I have a pipeline where i run a bunch of gradle cmds which gives me some output as values which i want to carry forward to next steps, now i know about >>GITHUB_ENV but i am trying to run the cmd and pass it to GITHUB_ENV in one go which does seems to work, so i am here to verify if there is a logic to do so

Here is a typical cmd

```
      - name: Pre Build
        env:
          ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_artifactory_user: "${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_USER }}"
          ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_artifactory_password: "${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN }}"
          ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_artifactory_contextUrl: "${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_INTERNAL_URL }}"
        run: |
          export testDataGenImageFull=$(./gradlew -PbuildNum=${GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER} -PgitSha=${gitSha} :perf-test-data-generator:printImageFullName | awk "/:printImageFullName/ {getline;print;}")
```

I need to redirect the varible value `testDataGenImageFull` to GITHUB_ENV so that other steps can use it

Tried this as well, did not worked

```
export testDataGenImageFull=$(./gradlew -PbuildNum=${GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER} -PgitSha=${gitSha} :perf-test-data-generator:printImageFullName | awk "/:printImageFullName/ {getline;print;}" >> GITHUB_ENV)
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to set the multiline value. See the mlutline syntax [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=bash#multiline-strings) in the docs. If you just want this in the next steps, you can simply dump this in a file and use that instead of an env var.